# How to loop through multiple URLs to scrape from a CSV file in Scrapy?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

My code for scrapping data from alibaba website:

```
import scrapy




class IndiamartSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'alibot'
    allowed_domains = ['alibaba.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/acrylic-wine-box_4.html']


    def parse(self, response):
        Title = response.xpath('//*[@class="title three-line"]/a/@title').extract()
        Price = response.xpath('//div[@class="price"]/b/text()').extract()
        Min_order = response.xpath('//div[@class="min-order"]/b/text()').extract()
        Response_rate = response.xpath('//i[@class="ui2-icon ui2-icon-skip"]/text()').extract()

        for item in zip(Title,Price,Min_order,Response_rate):
            scraped_info = {
                'Title':item[0],
                'Price': item[1],
                'Min_order':item[2],
                'Response_rate':item[3]

            }
            yield scraped_info
```

Notice the start url, it only scraps through the given URL, but i want this code to scrap all the urls present in my csv file. My csv file contains large amount of URLs. 
Sample of the data.csv file::

```
'https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/shock-absorber.html',
'https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/shock-wheel.html',
'https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/shoes-fastener.html',
'https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/shoes-women.html',
'https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/shoes.html',
'https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/shoulder-long-strip-bag.html',
'https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/shower-hair-band.html',
...........
```

How do i import all the links of csv file in the code at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correctly loop through a file without loading all of it into memory you should use generators, as both file objects and start_requests method in python/scrapy are generators:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'csv'

    def start_requests(self):
        with open('file.csv') as f:
            for line in f:
                if not line.strip():
                    continue
                yield Request(line)
```

To explain futher: 
Scrapy engine uses `start_requests` to generate requests as it goes. It will keep generating requests untill concurrent request limit is full (settings like `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`).
Also worth noting that by default scrapy crawls depth first - newer requests take priority, so start_requests loop will be last to finish.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there already. The only change is in `start_urls`, which you want to be "all the urls in the *.csv file." The following code easily implements that change.

```
with open('data.csv') as file:
    start_urls = [line.strip() for line in file]
```

Comment: where should i put the data.csv?

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.csv'

Comment: In the same directory as the python script. Otherwise, qualify the full path (e.g. `/home/uchiha/data.csv`)

Comment: This will load all csv data into memory and then crawl it. Now, depending on the size of your csv, you have a lot of memory completely wasted.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume you have stored url list in the form of a dataframe and you want to loop over each URL present inside the dataframe. My approach is given below which worked for me.

```
class IndiamartSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'alibot'
    #allowed_domains = ['alibaba.com']
    #start_urls = ['https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/acrylic-wine-box_4.html']
    

    def start_requests(self):
        df = pd.read_csv('fileContainingUrls.csv')
        #Here fileContainingUrls.csv is a csv file which has a column named as 'URLS'
        # contains all the urls which you want to loop over. 
        urlList = df['URLS'].to_list()
        for i in urlList:
             yield scrapy.Request(url = i, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
       Title = response.xpath('//*[@class="title three-line"]/a/@title').extract()
       Price = response.xpath('//div[@class="price"]/b/text()').extract()
       Min_order = response.xpath('//div[@class="min-order"]/b/text()').extract()
    
       for item in zip(Title,Price,Min_order,Response_rate):
           scraped_info = {
               'Title':item[0],
               'Price': item[1],
               'Min_order':item[2],
               'Response_rate':item[3]

           }
           yield scraped_info
```