# Scrape data from multiple URLs by manually creating them from data in a CSV file

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to get data from multiple start_URLs using the same scrapy spider file. My goal is to create multiple URLs by changing a particular ID in a web-address and run the spider in the sequence of IDs. All the IDs are saved in a CSV file. The formal name of my ID is CIK. For simplicity, I put two CIKs here (in the original file, I have around 19000 CIKs).

1326801

320193

So the manually created website should look like this:

https://www.secform4.com/insider-trading/1326801-0.htm

https://www.secform4.com/insider-trading/320193-0.htm

My question is: how can I import the CIKs saved in the CSV file, command scrapy spider to manually build Start_URLs and run the created URLs sequentially?

Also, some of these CIKs do not have data on the specific website. How may I command spider to ignore the unavailable URLs manually created?

I am just a beginner. If possible, please suggest me the specific changes in my code (specific code would be highly appreciated). Thank you in advance.

```
import scrapy
class InsiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'insider'
    cik = 320193
    allowed_domains = ['www.secform4.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.secform4.com/insider-trading/'+ str(cik) +'-0.htm']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop through multiple URLs to scrape from a CSV file in Scrapy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51914391/how-to-loop-through-multiple-urls-to-scrape-from-a-csv-file-in-scrapy)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to write all urls into start_urls, but this is not best practise.

Use

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'csv'

    def start_requests(self):
        with open('file.csv') as f:
            for line in f:
                if not line.strip():
                    continue
                yield Request(line)
```

shown in: 
[How to loop through multiple URLs to scrape from a CSV file in Scrapy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51914391/how-to-loop-through-multiple-urls-to-scrape-from-a-csv-file-in-scrapy)
instead.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas Strub, for your response. I used this particular code earlier. But I get the following 404 error and the codes do not scrap any data.

2019-11-22 04:25:31 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <404 https://www.secform4.com/insider-trading/320193
-0.htm>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed

Comment: Seems that there is a space between 320193 and "-0" .. is this the error?

Comment: Good point, Thomas. But I do not know, from where the space is coming. How may I drop the space?

 start_urls = ['https://www.secform4.com/insider-trading/'+ str(cik) +'-0.htm']

Comment: What is the result when you do as str(cik).strip() ?

Comment: with open('cik.csv') as f:
        for cik in f:
            if not str(cik).strip():
                continue
with this code, no improvement

Comment: the strip in this part: + str(cik) +

Answer (score 0):

```
df = '1326801', '320193'
urls = ['https://www.secform4.com/insider-trading/' + str(i) +'-0.htm' for i in df]
print(urls)
['https://www.secform4.com/insider-trading/1326801-0.htm', 'https://www.secform4.com/insider-trading/320193-0.htm']
```

Comment: please add context/explanation to your answer for others to be able to understand your solution. (End of Review).